# I can't use the permissions with my raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, root, user

I got a Raspberry PI and, even with the root user, I got some "permission denied" using commands like when I want to access the gpio.
I tried with and without sudo.
sample :

# cd /sys/class/gpio/

# ls

# sudo echo 24 > export
(Permission denied)

But I can create users and add them to the sudo list.
I don't understand, how can it be possible ?

Thanks to answer me.

Comment: "sudo echo" won't work, because "echo" is internal bash command and not a program or an executable script.

Comment: @lenik : Incorrect! Sort of. `echo` is a built-in, but there's also an executable (try `whereis echo`).  However, `/bin/echo foo > bar` still won't work. The problem is the output redirection (`>`) which is done by your current non-sudo shell, to a file you don't have permissions on.

Answer (score 3):

As lenik sayed, echo is a built-in and thus cannot be used with sudo like that.

But in your case, it's the redirection (>) which cause problem (thanks goldilocks). Indeed, the redirection is also made by the shell and thus have the same restriction than the built-ins.

Instead, you should switch to root first:

```
$ sudo su
# echo 24 > export
```

Or if you don't want to switch:

```
$ sudo su -c 'echo 24 > export'
```

Or, only for writing in a file:

```
$ echo 24 | sudo dd of=/sys/class/gpio
```

You can have a list of shell built-ins with the following command:

```
$ man builtins
```

Comment: +1 Except lenik is sort-of wrong (see my comment to the OP). There are some other ways around the problem, e.g. `echo 24 | sudo dd of=/sys/class/gpio`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I indeed didn't think about the redirection.